# Change format and replace zeros in a pipe

Tags: r

I wrote a pipe but it doesn't work

```
newdata_tibble %>%
  mutate("Order_TMS_1" = as.character(Order_TMS_1),
         "Cbm" = as.double(Cbm)) %>%
  gsub(",",".",Cbm) %>%
  format(round(.$Cbm:.$CHGW,digits,2),2) %>%
  na_if(.$REv_TMS_1:.$GP,0)
```

2 and 3 row of my code works. From forth row (gsub) to the end my code doesn't work properly.

In 4 row i want to replace commas for dots but it fails.
In 5th row i want to change doubles precision for a few columns (wchich are double type) but also doesn't work.
Last row - ineed to replace all NA with zeros but also doesn't work. I have double precision for some zero values eg. 0.00 or more like 0.0000 but I think it doesn't really matter here. How can I change my code to get it worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the steps can be merged together, also if we do `as.double/as.numeric` on a column with `,`, it would become NA.  So, we need to replace it first and then convert to `double`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
newdata_tibble %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(Cbm = as.numeric(str_replace(Cbm, ",", "."))) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Cbm:CHGW),  ~format(round(., 2), 2)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(REv_TMS_1:GP), na_if, 0)
```

Comment: When I execute the code I can see a tibble in console window with changed column types. However when I check them with sapply(newdata_tibble, class) then column types are as original ones, not changed (originally 'Cbm' is character and 'Order_TMS_1' is numeric). I think that's a problem. Why column types didn't change in original table after using this code? The rest of the code doesn't work properly as well..

Comment: @Muska You just need to assign `newdata_tibble <- newdata_tibble %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(Cbm = as.numeric(str_replace(Cbm, ",", ".")) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Cbm:CHGW),  ~format(round(., 2), 2)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(REv_TMS_1:GP), na_if, 0)`

Comment: @Muska I find a missing bracket, in `mutate` step, fixed

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would have helped to better understand the data and test possible solutions but for time being you can try if the following solution works for you.

```
library(dplyr)

newdata_tibble %>%
   mutate(Order_TMS_1 = as.character(Order_TMS_1),
          Cbm = as.double(Cbm),
          Cbm = gsub(",",".",Cbm)) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Cbm:CHGW), ~format(round(., 2), 2)) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(REv_TMS_1:GP), na_if, 0)
```